# How to create an image from multiple images

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I want to build an image dynamically using NodeJS and gm. For example, I have a base image, then an image from a sprite sheet that needs to be placed in the upper left corner approx. 10px from the top and left. Then I need to write some text aligned right 10px from top and right. Then I need to place an image 30px from the left 20px from the top, etc. I did this in php once, but now I need to do it in NodeJS How can this be accomplished? (If it can)

Comment: Try something, anything. Then post a snippet and folks can help out.

Comment: I can't find any info on how to do this at all. The documentation, in my opinion, is very poorly done. As far as I can find, there is no documented way to handle something like this. The drawing methods are for primitives only: http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#drawing-primitives

Comment: I mean, there is `append`, but it doesn't give you any control over the positioning and sizing of the appended image.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `composite` method see docs from GM

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/composite.html

`append` is normally handy for creating sprites, not building composites (overlays) of several images. Sorry I don't have time for a more in depth example.